# How to change default shell for a network user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, zsh, administrator

I am working with Ubuntu and I would like to change my default shell to z shell. I cannot use the `chsh -s /bin/zsh` or `chsh-s /bin/sh myuser` command since my user name does not exist in `/etc/passwd` and it's actually a network user. Any idea to work around it and make zsh my default shell?

Comment: I currently load zsh using `.bashrc` but I am looking for the actual solution.

Comment: Where is your Ubuntu box getting its list of network users from? An LDAP server or something? Did you try fixing your record in that LDAP server?

Comment: I have no idea! How?

Comment: If you get your user account from a NIS server, `ypchsh` where _yp_ stands for _yellow pages_ might work. But for a precise solution you need to provide more details...